# Hovering effects do not work in mobile browser

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the hovering effect on a mobile browser. I have a hovering effect on the circle(text appears only when the mouse hovers on it). 
I want to make the hovering effects work on a mobile browser. My solution works perfectly on the laptop, but when I open the website on the iPhone, it does not show text inside the circle. So, I want to make this work on mobile too. I also have a hovering effect on the button which works perfectly. I guess I need to make the circles clickable. 
How can I solve this problem?

Here is my HTML code of the circle :

```
    <ul class="circles">
      <li>
        <div class="item img-1-services">
          <div class="circle-info">
            <p class="service">text</p></div>
        </div>
        <h4>English classes</h4></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
      </ul>
```

Here is my css

CSS:

```
 .item {
      width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;
        box-shadow: 
            inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255,255,255,0.6),
            0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      text-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .circles li {
      width: 320px;
      height: 320px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 20px;

    }

    .circle-info {
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        border-radius: 50%; 
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transform: scale(0);
    }
    .item:hover {
        box-shadow: 
            inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .item:hover .circle-info {
        transform: scale(1);
    }**
```

This is just one circle, I have 7 of them and each one should show the text.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could add onclick="void(0)" to whatever element you need to be seen as clickable.

Comment: Can you please give an example of using onclick="void(0)" ? I'm not sure how to use it correctly.

Comment: How can you add a hover effect to a mobile website? You've either clicked the element by touching the screen or you haven't touched the element yet

Answer (score 0):

your question is confusing please explain it clearly. I'm assuming that you are asking to display or show the text when a user mouseover the circle. If your question is this then this solution might resolve your problem.

One more Important thing your HTML markup is incorrect as you are not closing the UL tag and you have few extra closing divs this might create unexpected errors.

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.circles li {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;

}

.item:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text{font-size: 26px!important;display:none}

.item:hover #text {
    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<h4>English classes</h4>
  <ul class="circles">
      <li class='item'>
      <span id='text'>Text</span>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I wat to make the hovering effects work on a mobile browser.  My solution perfectly works on the laptop, but when I open the website on the iPhone, it does not show text inside the circle. So, I want to make this work on mobile too. Regarding ul, I have 7 of them and I uploaded code for only one circle that's why my ul is not closed. I didn't notice it here, will edit. Thank you for noticing.